# How to make RxJS cancel a debounced http call before next debounce ends?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an input field that updates a model via a REST api.

1. User writes "e"
2. User waits 400ms (time of the debounce)
3. The http call for updating the backend models fire
4. User quickly writes "eeeeeee"
5. The http call comes back with the updated model and this overwrites the current model in the frontend
6. The text input changes back to "e" without the user doing anything

The code I have now looks like this (RxJS 5.0.0-beta.6):

```
this.textInput
    .valueChanges
    .map(change => this.item.text = change)
    .debounceTime(400)
    .switchMap(
        change => this.itemService.save(item)
    )
    .subscribe(updatedItem => this.item = updatedItem)
```

What I want to happen is that if the user writes more text it should cancel the previous http call even though we are still waiting for the debounce to finish.

> PS: `flatMapLates()` was renamed to `switchMap()` in RxJS 5

Comment: Is this really an Rx problem? simply treat the client as the authority. If the client has data, assume the client is right

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`flatMapLatest`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md) operator. It is like `flatMap` but will unsubscribe from stream when new value arrives.

Also keep in mind that `this.itemService.save(item)` should return disposable that will cancel XHR request on dispose.

Here I've created [jsbin for you](https://jsbin.com/zahahu/edit?html,js,output) to show how it works (Open network tab whule typing and you will see cancelled requests)